# Hooking Empty to a Plane

Tags: transforms

I try to apply these effects shown in this screen. But I couldn't complete it. As far as I can see, Wintermute hooks the Empty to the Plane and do some scale changes on it.

[image]
[Original article - Bar graph transition](https://wintermutedigital.com/post/motion-gfx-0/)
[Video tutorial](https://youtu.be/AONniAlLjLg?t=565)

I tried lots of options to hook and try to change its scale like him but I failed. The closest result I get it with is the *Stretch to* option of *Object Constraints*. How can set it properly?

[image]

Comment: please provide blend file so i can help you

Comment: @Chris Sorry, I attach now. https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1HKKq_joJ1nqkpmFqoGzP3Qh7AI7BhrjC?usp=sharing

Comment: https://blender.stackexchange.com/tour

Comment: @Wiredisc external links are not allowed as a main source of informations. Please next time use https://blend-exchange.com to attach blend file Thank you

Answer (score 3):

*I don't know where you failed, but according to your blend ...*

You created a vertex group "hook", but you didn't **Assign** two top vertices to this group.

[image]

When you *Assign* two top vertices to *Plane*, position Empty on top Plane's edge, add *Hook* modifier, set *Object* > *Empty* and *Vertex Group* > *hook*

[image: modifier]

Than Duplicate Plane (so you don't have to set modifier for each) and change **Strenght** value for each 1 / 0.8 / 0.6 / 0.4 / 0.2

Now when you move *Empty* along *Y axis* bars are scaled accordingly ...

[image]

Comment: isn't this the opposite of your second sentence? ;)
1) I don't know where you failed, but according to your blend ...
2) You created a vertex group "hook", but you didn't Assign two top vertices to this group. But i like your nice answer -> upvoted!

Comment: Thank you guys so much !

Comment: @Chris Yes it sounds probably confusing ... I just wasn't sure if the blend file is at his final state of following tut or base blend with just a steps that was clear for him ... like there wasn't set any modifiers, that was mentioned as something he tried already.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't a direct answer to your question, but it may be an option.. If a bar-graph wipe is what you're looking for, you could do it with a relatively simple shader, rather than geometry and hooks. It might be more flexible.

You would make a node tree which makes a mask by asking whether Y is less than some function of stepped X. Here, the range of X is the 0-1 of the *Generated* texture-space of a plane, stepped by a *Map Range* node.

[image]

.. which generates a mask something like the one below. In this case, f(X) is the cosine of `pi*X`, and the animation results from directly messing with the amplitude (Y scale) and Y offset of the function, in the *Multiply Add* maths node, and keyframing those values. But it could be any function you like, animated in any sense.

[image]

If you *did* want to control the graph using the position of an Empty, you could use a cluster like this, somewhere in f(X):

[image]

.. which will return the X of the Empty, in the plane's space, in Blender units. (If the plane is scaled in Object Mode, the units will scale with them).

If you want color, or some other per-bar attribute, you can pipe the noodle labelled  'Color Branch' in the first illustration through a *Color Ramp*, and multiply with the mask:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Oh ... magician on board !!! Awesome solution, thank you ... I just feel like my brain works in analog way :)

Comment: Thank you, I'm looking at now !

Answer (score 1):

what you are trying to achieve is that bar graph look? In the tutorial time skip it skipped to the triangle one which was the last one not the bar graph.

Anyway with the actual blender itself. I saw the end result of the animation and made it myself in blender. Also the thing you missed im pretty sure is the vertex groups.

Make sure you make a vertex group of only the single line otherwise the mesh wont deform like it did in the video. Just make sure you did all the steps correctly. Heres a video of me doing it:

https://www.mediafire.com/file/v7a17ku510z9dm9/asdasdasdasd.mp4/file
i compressed it alot using movie maker. Does anyone know a better method of showing videos like this other then this way?

Comment: Thank you so much !

Comment: I think you can try google drive for uploading videos